# How long should a query that returns 5 million records take?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I realise the answer should probably be 'as little time as possible' but I'm trying to learn how to optimise databases and I have no idea what an acceptable time is for my hardware.

For a start I'm using my local machine with a copy of sql server 2008 express. I have a dual-core processor, 2GB ram and a 64bit OS (if that makes a difference). I'm only using a simple table with about 6 `varchar` fields.

At first I queried the data without any indexing. This took a ridiculously long amount of time so I cancelled and added a clustered index (using the PK) to the table. This cut the time down to 1 minute 14 sec. I have no idea if this is the best I can get or whether I'm still able to cut this down even further?

Am I limited by my hardware or is there anything else I can do to my table/database/queries to get results faster?

FYI I'm only using a standard `SELECT * FROM <Table>` to retrieve my results.

---

EDIT: Just to clarify, I'm only doing this for testing purposes. I don't NEED to pull out all the data, I'm just using that as a consistent test to see if I can cut down the query times.

I suppose what I'm asking is: Is there anything I can do to speed up the performance of my queries other than a) upgrading hardware and b) adding indexes (assuming the schema is already good)?

Comment: FYI you should probably test by inserting into a `#TEMP` table instead of just selecting it.  You will definitely be paying for display overhead for SSMS to show all 5m rows, and it will eat into your memory and IO

Comment: To speed it up, try to avoid using '*' and just ask for the data you want

Comment: +1 for Matt's suggestion of just ask for the data you want... for example, if all you want is the id and name of a row, you can do "select id, name from ..."

Comment: @alimac83 Would you share more about your runtime environment with some hardware info? Also please, add how to call `SELECT * FROM`, thanks.

Answer (score 15):

I think you are asking the wrong question.

First of all - why do you need so many articles at one time on the local machine? What do you want to do with them? I'm asking because I think you want to transfer this of data to somewhere, so you should be measuring how long it takes to transfer the data.

Some advice:

Your applications **should not** select 5 million records at the time. Try to split your query and get the data in smaller sets.

UPDATE:

Because you are doing this for testing, I suggest that you

1. Remove `*` from your query - it takes SQL server some time to resolve this.
2. Put your data in temporary storage, try using `VIEW` or a temporary table for this.
3. Use [plan caching on your server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee343986%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

to improve performance.  But even if you're just testing, I still don't understand why you would need such tests if your application would never use such a query. **Testing just for the sake of testing is a bad use of time**

Comment: And I would add that optimizing for issues found in those tests, which I assume is the reason for running them, would be an even bigger waste of time.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but the guy might have been practicing and familiarizing themselves with Query Tuning.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the query execution plan. If your query is doing a table scan, it will obviously take a long time. The query execution plan can help you decide what kind of indexing you would need on the table. Also, creating table partitions can help sometimes in cases where the data is partitioned by a condition (usually date and time).

Answer (score 2):

The best optimized way depends on the indexing strategy you choose. As many of the above answers, i too would say partitioning the table would help sometimes. And its not the best practice to query all the billion record in a single time frame. Will give you much better results if you could try to query partially with the iterations. you may check this link to clear the doubts on the minimum requirements for the Sql server 2008 [Minimum H/W and S/W Requirements for Sql server 2008](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

I did 5.5 million in 20 seconds.  That's taking over 100k schedules with different frequencies and forecasting them for the next 25 years.  Just max scenario testing, but proves the speed you can achieve in a scheduling system as an example.

Comment: Would you share more about your runtime environment with some hardware info? Also please, if you used `SELECT * FROM`, how to call the command, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When fecthing 5 million rows you are almost 100% going spool to tempdb. you should try to optimize your temp Db by adding additional files. if you have multiple drives on seperate disks you should split the table data into different ndf files located on seperate disks. parititioning wont help when querying all the data on the disk 
 U can also use a query hint to force parrallelism MAXDOP this will increase the CPU utilization. Ensure that the columns contain few nulls as possible and rebuild ur indexes and stats